# How does one get Visual Studio Code development environment to use '/' for paths in windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

Instead of using '\' it would be helpful to be able to use '/' so compatible with linux and would not need double '\' everywhere.

Well I guess I was not clear enough :(

Visual_studio_code is an open source development environment and throughout the application it uses '\' instead of '/' for path delimitation. I'd like to change it's default to '/' and was wondering it anybody knew how?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: If you use C++17, you might find this useful: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path

Comment: While not answering all of your question, if you prepend the string with @, you don't have to escape the backslash.  For example:  @"c:\temp\file.txt"